# blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: angular, spring, jwt, cors

ive a spring boot app with angular front deployed in heroku. I configurated my spring backed to disable cors errors and ive had no problems until i implemented jwt authentication in my app. Then suddenly ive cors problems again. More specifically, appears this error:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://serene-wave-12377.herokuapp.com/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:49720' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Ive tried everything ive seen, but i still get this error.

**my webSecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final userService userService;

    public WebSecurityConfig(userService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests() // authorize
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // all requests are authenticated
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

**springBootApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(HibernateProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("*").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
```

}

**UserController:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", exposedHeaders="Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {  //methods
```

**Ive also tried in my front end angular app:**

```
  register(registerForm: any): Observable<any> {
    let body = {
      email: registerForm.email,
      password: registerForm.password,
      name: registerForm.name,
      surname: registerForm.surname,
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('content-type', 'application/json')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return this.http.post(
      'https://serene-wave-12377.herokuapp.com/api/register',
      body
    ),  { 'headers': headers };
  }
```

Nothing works. I appreciate a lot any help/idea you guys may suggest. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `WebSecurityConfig` classes `configure` method. When you implement Spring security, it overrides the cors configs you implemented before. To overcome that issue, you have to add
`http.cors().and()`
at the beginning of the `configure` method. So, by changing the `configure` method implementation to follows, would work.

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().and().httpBasic();
                http.headers().cacheControl();
```